# sed syntax to remove 2 characters only when it is box and space

Tags: sed

I have a `sed` expression to remove the first 2 characters from all the lines in a file.

```
sed 's/^..//' raw.txt > converted.txt
```

However, the problem is some lines are large and get appended to the next line. For example,if I consider the input as in the below lines,

```
□ I have box and space in front
□ I am a large line which will
get appended to next line.
□ I am another line.
```

As per my `sed` syntax, I am getting the output as,

```
I have box and space in front
I am a large line which will
t appended to next line. 
I am another line.
```

However, the output am expecting is,

```
I have box and space in front. 
I am a large line which will get appended to next line. 
I am another line.
```

How should I modify the sed expression to achieve this?

Comment: perhaps `s/^[^A-Za-z]//` will work

Comment: yeah, I am getting all the characters. But I am still trying to figure out to get the output as I had mentioned in my expected output.

Comment: Do you actually have a `□` or does that represent a space?

Comment: it's also possible that `□` is a multichar utf8 character.

Comment: Yeah, I get the box from a web page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '
    {
        if (/^□ /) {
            if (prev_line) 
                print prev_line
            prev_line = substr($0, 3)
        } else {
            prev_line = prev_line " " $0
        }
    }    
    END {print prev_line}
' raw.txt
```

```
I have box and space in front
I am a large line which will get appended to next line.
I am another line.
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Might be easier with `awk`:

```
awk '{
       if (/^□ /) printf "%s", (NR>1?"\n":"") substr($0,3)
       else printf " %s", $0
     }
     END {if (NR>0) print ""}'
```

Comment: This one works as expected. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your file is not huge and you can load it directly into memory, this should work:

```
$ perl -000pe 's/\n([^□])/ $1/g; s/^□ //mg;' raw.txt 
I have box and space in front
I am a large line which will et appended to next line.
I am another line.
```

The `-000` activates paragraph mode and (assuming there are no consecutive newlines in your file) will load the whole file into the special variable `$_`. You then do the necessary replacements and the `-p` causes `$_` to be printed automatically.

Comment: This one seems a pretty elegant solution. Thanks!

Comment: I would anchor the 2nd substitution: `s/^□ //mg`

Comment: @glennjackman good point, I've done so. And thanks for catching the bug too.